# Mac OS X equivalent to Windows "Register this connection's addresses in DNS"

Tags: macos, osx-server, dns

On Windows, in the Advanced TCP/IP Properties of the TCP/IPv4 properties of the NIC there is a tickbox called "Register this connection's addresses in DNS".

Does Mac OS X have an equivalent setting?  I need to disable it, as we have a Mac OS X 10.10 Server with 3 NICs that is autoregistering in the office DNS server (which is a Windows 2012 server btw) and it is registering the same hostname on all 3 NICs, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dsconfigad -restrictDDNS en0

Will only allow the address assigned to en0 to be registered via DDNS.

Best practice is to have all NICs disabled except en0 when you bind the Mac.  Then restrict DDNS updates to only en0, only after this then enabling the subsequent NICs.